# hashing a 32bit integer is slower than bitwise operation on hash of 3 16bit integers?

Tags: c++, performance-testing, benchmarking, compiler-optimization

I am working on latency-sensitive software. Today, I decided to make my struct smaller in size by using BitField structs inside a union and read that BitField struct as an integer that I use as the unique key for my hash function. I was expecting to get slightly (if not a lot) better performance from my hash on unique key than bitwise operation on the hash of attribute of my class, but it turns out doing bitwise operation to get the hash key is much much faster? I have been trying to find out why, but I was not able to come up with any conclusion.

here is my code: http://quick-bench.com/OkNuVOxdVtW8g7OWUXjqcvYlNrs

```
#include <functional>

struct GroupTupleInformation {
  unsigned int src : 12;
  unsigned int dst : 12;
  unsigned int flow_id : 8;
};

union GroupTupleData {
  GroupTupleInformation info;
  uint32_t hash_key;
};

struct GroupTuple {
  constexpr void setSrc(uint16_t s) noexcept { data.info.src = s; }

  constexpr uint16_t getSrc() const noexcept { return data.info.src; }

  constexpr void setDst(uint16_t d) noexcept { data.info.dst = d; }

  constexpr uint16_t getDst() const noexcept { return data.info.dst; }

  constexpr void setFlowId(uint8_t f) noexcept { data.info.flow_id = f; }

  constexpr uint8_t getFlowId() const noexcept { return data.info.flow_id; }

  constexpr uint32_t getHashKey() const noexcept { return data.hash_key; }

 private:
  GroupTupleData data;
};

struct UnionHashFn {
  constexpr std::size_t operator()(const GroupTuple& gtup) const noexcept {
    return gtup.getHashKey();
  }
};

struct CombinedHashFn {
  std::size_t operator()(const GroupTuple& gtup) const noexcept {
    std::hash<uint16_t> hasher{};
    return hasher(gtup.getSrc()) ^ hasher(gtup.getDst()) ^
           hasher(gtup.getFlowId());
  }
};


static void UnionHashFnBench(benchmark::State& state) {
  unsigned long i = 0;
  UnionHashFn hasher;
  GroupTuple group_tuple;

  size_t key = 0;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    group_tuple.setSrc(i++ % 32);
    group_tuple.setDst(i++ % 32);
    group_tuple.setFlowId(i++ % 32);
    key = hasher(group_tuple);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(key);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(UnionHashFnBench);

static void CombinedHashFnBench(benchmark::State& state) {
  unsigned long i = 0;
  CombinedHashFn hasher;
  GroupTuple group_tuple;

  size_t key = 0;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    group_tuple.setSrc(i++ % 32);
    group_tuple.setDst(i++ % 32);
    group_tuple.setFlowId(i++ % 32);
    key = hasher(group_tuple);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(key);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(CombinedHashFnBench);
```

PS: I know benchmaking a map or unordered_map is more complicated that benchmarking the cost of hash function, and I am also aware of the bitwise operation I did for getting hash out of my class is not a good way of getting hash, it is just for the sake of having a simple example

Comment: It takes ***extra*** CPU cycles to unpack a bitfield from a memory word. To update the bit field, you have to ***read*** the memory word, then ***write*** it back, with just the selected bits updated; as opposed to simply writing a single memory word.

Comment: Uh oh. Bitfields. These always seem like a good idea, but it's rarely the case that it ends up that way in retrospect. Why not simple bitmasks? At least that way you know what's going on internally, instead of so much of that being hidden.

Comment: @tadman because two of my teammates are not comfortable and scared of bitmasks, so I used bitfields for its easy to understand interface.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: what you said about updating a bitfield makes sense, but how would it affect reading the GroupTupleData.hash_key in the union? shouldn't it just interpret the bitfield as an unsiged integer ?!

Comment: Ah, I guess they'll learn to be scared of bitfields more than bitmasks in time. Unless you have billions of these things shaving four bits off a value probably isn't worth the trouble. Have you benchmarked a non-bitfield version, just a plain struct, to see how it performs both in terms of speed and memory use? It'll push you into a 64-bit value but that won't be the end of the world on a modern system.

Comment: "Interpreting" the bitfield will involve at least an extra shifting and a masking operation, for every access to it. Same thing you'll have to do when manually implementing bitfields directly. Try to declare a single `uint32_t`, then write the code that reads and writes individual bit fields out of it. Just because you declare a bitfield using native C++ support for it does not mean you're waving a magic wand and make that extra overhead go away. The compiler will, pretty much, generate the same code you will be manually writing out yourself.

Comment: "because two of my teammates are not comfortable and scared of bitmasks" you are working on low latency software and teammates are scared on bitmasks?  Really? How about cache line, that makes them crazy?

Comment: "I decided to make my struct smaller in size" usually (not always though) you win speed you loose memory and vice versa. So if you are on low latency world you should not save bits.

Comment: There's one case that you win both speed and memory, that's when you have a very big array that doesn't fit into cache. The cost of cache misses far exceeds the cost of bitwise operations so you'll want to make the elements smaller. Otherwise you'll want to keep fields separately. That's why memory alignment exists and why small arguments are still passed as the whole registers in assembly ABIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::hash<uint16_t>` is just identity (which is questionable, to be honest), so the expression:

`hasher(gtup.getSrc()) ^ hasher(gtup.getDst()) ^ hasher(gtup.getFlowId())`

will be optimized to a very simple expression. Its code is just:

```
   lea    -0x2(%rax),%ecx
   lea    -0x1(%rax),%edx
   xor    %ecx,%edx
   xor    %eax,%edx
   and    $0x1f,%edx
```

On the other hand, calculating `hash_key` takes more effort:

```
   mov    %edx,%esi
   and    $0x1f,%esi
   mov    %ecx,%edi
   and    $0x1f000,%edi
   or     %rsi,%rdi
   add    $0x3,%rdx
   mov    %eax,%esi
   and    $0x1f000000,%esi
   or     %rdi,%rsi
```

So it is not surprising that the `hash_key` approach is slower.